# Node.js and parallel access to files

Tags: node.js, multithreading, file, io, thread-safety

In my node.js application I have some generic storage-class, which is used to read/write javascript objects to single files on the filesystem. Basically I will have a `get` function which reads a single file, and a `set` function which writes a single file.

Now, those operations are triggered from http request. Since both network as well as file i/o is non-blocking and done in a background thread, this will lead to the `get` and `set` firing read/write operations on the same file at the same time.

What would be the best approach to avoid data inconsistency/parallel access to the files?

I thought about writing stuff down to disk only every xxx seconds and when reading, keep stuff in memory, but this would leave the very same problem to the situation when stuff is beeing written down at the same time where some file is not in memory already, thus resulting in the same problem above.

Then I thought about keeping flags in memory for each file, indicating whether some IO is pending, which will be reset in the `fs.readFile/fs.writeFile` callbacks. I could then check those flags in e.g. the `get`, and postpone the operation. Maybe I could build a stack of pending IO callbacks, which is filled by `get` when IO must be done later, and will be emptied by the `fs.readFile/fs.writeFile`.
Would this be any good?

Any more hints/suggestions on this topic?

Comment: Interesting problem - but I think you first need to confirm that this issue does arise - for instance you could use a module like `asyc` and use its `async.parallel` - in one function write to the file and in the other read from the same file - see if you encounter issues. Here is the [async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

Comment: Its like `app.use(req, res, next) { if (yxz) storage.get(fileOf(req)); else storage.set(fileOf(req)); } ` (minimal pseudo-example).
I cannot see how I could build a stack of operations from operations triggered by different requests.
[edit]
Maybe the best approach would be changing everything to the -sync versions, and introduce caching on the storage-class level to maintain a viable speed.

Comment: I agree with the idea of a queue of operations, you will take a look to this https://github.com/d3/d3-queue there seems to be an example with your use case